# Mute conflicting webview audio programatically

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webview

I have a media player application, which plays FM radio or songs. The problem statement now is to add a section where users can play simple H5 (html) games in a webview. The issue I'm facing is that some of these games have music/audio within them.

I don't want the webview to play any sounds on launch which will overlap with the FM/songs which are playing. Have no control over the H5 games' code and have tried injecting javascript which finds all the audio elements using `getElementsByTagName` and tries to mute them. Unfortunately, it is not working for the games. Please do suggest any feasible approach here.